# Systemd scheduling task for January 1st when told to do it after the 15th

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd timer set to scrub my btrfs filesystem, but I can't get the scheduling right. The timer file at /etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub.timer is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Scrub btrfs filesystem, verify block checksums
Documentation=man:btrfs-scrub

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Fri *-*-15..21 18:00:00
AccuracySec=1h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and `systemd-analyze calendar "Fri *-*-15..21 18:00:00"` gives me

```
Normalized form: Fri *-*-15..21 18:00:00    
    Next elapse: Fri 2021-01-15 18:00:00 EST
       (in UTC): Fri 2021-01-15 23:00:00 UTC
       From now: 3 weeks 3 days left
```

But according to `sudo systemctl status btrfs-scrub.timer` it's scheduled for January 1st.

```
● btrfs-scrub.timer - Scrub btrfs filesystem, verify block checksums
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/btrfs-scrub.timer.d
           └─schedule.conf
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2020-12-22 04:09:32 EST; 4s ago
  Trigger: Fri 2021-01-01 00:00:00 EST; 1 weeks 2 days left
     Docs: man:btrfs-scrub
```

I've reset the timer, but it keeps scheduling for Jan 1. Where am I going wrong? I'm using systemd 237 on Ubuntu